# HighCharts Custom SVG Marker Symbol

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

Based on the [Highcharts documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.marker.symbol) you can create your own point marker by defining a custom callback for an (SVG-based) symbol path.

However, what if you need to get at the underlying series data from within the symbol prototype function? Is that possible?

For instance:

```js
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross = function (x, y, w, h) {

    // I want to be able to access the series data from here. 
    // Either the point data or the entire series' data array.
           
    return ['M', x, y, 'L', x + w, y + h, 'M', x + w, y, 'L', x, y + h, 'z'];
};

if (Highcharts.VMLRenderer) {
    Highcharts.VMLRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross = Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross;
}


Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Demo of predefined, image and custom marker symbols'
    },

    legend: {
        y: -40 // make room for subtitle
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Custom symbol',
        data: [54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6],
        marker: {
            symbol: 'cross',
            lineColor: null,
            lineWidth: 2
        }
    }],

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: '*) Base64 not supported in IE6 and IE7',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        align: 'right',
        y: null,
        style: {
            fontSize: '10px'
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible... Could explain why you would need that? Maybe there's another way to achieve what you want

Comment: Why not storage the data as a global array, then you can access them anywhere.

Comment: Can you explain your question in more details and what should be the final result?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, you can actually define the marker properties at the individual point level. From there, you can provide the value and make it accessible from within the custom callback.

Like so:

```js
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross = function(x, y, w, h, d) {

  // I want to be able to access the series data from here. 
  // Either the point data or the entire series' data array.
  if (d.v) {
    console.debug("Point-specific data: " + d.v);
  }

  // From here, you can imagine one can use the point-specific data to affect the symbol path. 
  // A good example would be to in case you want to build a series of custom wind barbs, 
  // in which the path of the barb will be based on the intensity and direction of each point 
  // ...

  return ['M', x, y, 'L', x + w, y + h, 'M', x + w, y, 'L', x, y + h, 'z'];
};

if (Highcharts.VMLRenderer) {
  Highcharts.VMLRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross = Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross;
}


Highcharts.chart('container', {

  title: {
    text: 'Demo of predefined, image and custom marker symbols'
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Custom symbol',
    data: [{
        x: 1525089600000,
        y: 54.4,
        marker: {
          symbol: "cross",
          v: 54.4
        }
      },

      {
        x: 1525090500000,
        y: 71.5,
        marker: {
          symbol: "cross",
          v: 71.5
        }
      },

      {
        x: 1525091400000,
        y: 29.9,
        marker: {
          symbol: "cross",
          v: 29.9
        }
      }

    ],
    marker: {
      symbol: 'cross',
      lineColor: null,
      lineWidth: 2
    }
  }],


});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```