# Highchart custom marker type SVGs

Tags: highcharts, series

We are trying to add more marker types to our charts but we are wondering what the SVG specifications would be. We added some SVGs from an icon pack,
but we are unable to change the colours dynamically just as the default markers behave. If you could point us in the right direction on how to create SVGs similar to the default ones you will be doing us a whole world of good.

Comment: This question has been asked many times on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871605/highcharts-fill-series-color-on-svg-marker
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831055/custom-svg-symbol-using-highcharts-in-angular
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070693/highcharts-custom-svg-marker-symbol
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521397/how-to-use-existing-svg-symbols-in-a-file-as-markers-in-highcharts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highcharts - Get crossing point of crossing series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426603/highcharts-get-crossing-point-of-crossing-series)

Comment: Thanks this helped. But when I draw a square or triangle any tip on how to remove the fill? I want to draw a shape without fill

Comment: could you reproduce your attempt?

Comment: I was able to reproduce

Comment: Could you share a link to the demo?